# Remove computer/user safely from Windows domain to be decommissioned

Tags: domain, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I am a small business owner.  It currently has a Windows domain server, I want to decommission that and run existing client as non-domain standalone workstation.

The domain controller runs SBS 2008.  In a few weeks' time it will be decommissioned.  No domain will be put in its place.

I have a client workstation.  It is joined to the SBS domain.  I (normally) log on as a domain (admin) user.  It runs Windows Server 2008 R2.  However it acts purely as a client, like any other (non-server) OS client would.  It is only a server because it is/was used for development.

It is vital I retain this client machine, for legacy support etc.  I wish now to have it as a standalone PC like any other, not joined to any domain.

I have done a fair bit of browsing articles about leaving a domain.  There are various suggested approaches, both for SBS or more generally Windows Server domain.  But I am very hesitant before doing anything, because it would be disastrous if I made a false step, such as locking myself out or being unable to access files, etc.  For example, I would not be able to insert a password recovery or reinstall the current OS or anything it might need.  It would also be very difficult to physically reconnect it to the SBS server which is shortly to be decommissioned.  (I can connect to it over VPN, just not directly, if that makes any difference.)  So I really need to proceed carefully and safely!

I have ensured that I have a local administrative user on the client with which I can log on.  Which is presumably the most important thing.

I feel my first step would be as per [Removing a computer from the domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/699590/removing-a-computer-from-the-domain).  There from **Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings** I would change from belonging to the domain over to plain **Workgroup**.  I am hoping that if there is a problem I could then revert to the original domain.  Though I am not sure I would be able to revert without being physically locally connected to the SBS domain controller, which would be problematic?

If that goes well I would then think I should go to **Programs and Features** and run **Windows Small Business Server 2008 ClientAgent** to *uninstall* it, to remove any vestiges of the client trying to connect to the domain?

One issue I see is that I have been working, and saving files, as `DOMAIN\user`.  Once the domain is gone I will be logging on as `LOCALMACHINE\user`.  As I said, that is a local Admin user.  Nonetheless I worry about accessing existing files.  However, I have had a look and files (those I have looked at) seemed to have permissions and be owned by `LOCALMACHINE\Administrators` Group rather than `DOMAIN\user` User.

I can manually resurrect/copy my Desktop from domain to local user.  There will be some software which is perhaps installed only for current user, and goodness knows what entries in registry under the domain user's `HKEY_USERS\S-...`.  I don't know if there is anything easy I can do about this?

[The other alternative would be to do nothing at all?  Leave computer on domain, continue to log on locally as that domain user.  However, I am very concerned that at *some* point in the future my locally cached password might expire, or some action might *require* connecting to the domain, at which point I would be stuck.  So I think I am right that I would indeed be best removing this client from the domain?]

Thank for reading.  Sorry if this is long, I wanted to be clear.

Any and all advice gratefully received.  Can I start by changing the workstation over from Domain to **Workgroup** membership, *safe* in the knowledge that I can revert to domain if I need to, or not?

Comment: the question is, how many workstation are affected and how many  gpo's has been used so far? remind that you will have then to set every user pc manually correctly and even file access isn't easy as before anymore

Comment: This is it!  It's just the one PC left, presently on the domain.  And just my user.  Hence the downsizing and wish to get rid of any domain or server, and just use the PC as standalone now.  Does that allow you to answer?  There ought be a way to remove a client robustly from the domain for this purpose?  Unless you think I should just never remove if from the domain, even though i won't have a domain controller any longer?  But as I said that frightens me that *some time* in the future it will want to re-authenticate me and I will be in trouble?

Comment: the question is, why did you use a domain when only one pc is inside? Office 365 could do similar jobs. If you can work a whole month with a fresh installed windows and you don't have any trouble, then you can abandon your server

Comment: Because as I said there used to be many clients in the domain and now I am downsizing.  Office 365 has nothing to do with whether you need a domain, and the remaining machine has no interest in running it.  I am not interested in "a fresh installed windows", as I said I am interested in retaining an existing Windows machine as-is for legacy reasons but moving it from client to standalone without encountering problems.

Comment: normally, it can be done, but you may remove or reset the GPo cache.